# Какой метод хэширования лучше md5 или SHA-1 для безопасного пароля?

Tags: криптография, md5, sha1

Какой хэширования лучше `md5` или `SHA-1` для безопасного пароля?
Например такой `md5` хэширования `$password = md5($password);` и я хочу изменить на `SHA-1` хэширования , можно просто изменить так `$password = sha1($password);`?

Comment: До того как перешёл на password_hash() я использовал md5(md5(password.salt));
где salt это статичные данные из профиля пользователя, например дата регистрации.
Но это, конечно, не решает проблему коллизий.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`md5` и `sha-1` - это не способы шифрования. Это способы вычисления хэша (хэш-функции). Они используются не для того, чтобы "зашифровать" пароль. Они используются для того, чтобы не хранить пароль вообще.

В случае, если вы используете длинную соль (сейчас вы ее не используете вообще), "криптостойкость" хэшей практически одинаковая - злоумышленнику, укравшему базу, в любом случае придется перебирать пароли достаточно долго.

Поэтому основное требование к хэш-функции - минимальная вероятность коллизий - нахождения другой входной строки, на котором хэш-функция выдаст тот же результат. Потому что всегда есть вероятность что хэш пароля `password` совпадет с хэшем пароля `VFst4S3g5e%#%#gsgfdgb`. И при попытке подобрать пароль по словарю или брутфорсом злоумышленника пустит на сайт под простым паролем.

Эта ситуация маловероятна, но тем не менее - вероятность коллизий в `sha-1` намного меньше, чем в древнем `md5`. Поэтому использование `sha-1` или других новых алгоритмов - более предпочтительный вариант.

UPD: я специально не рассматривал случай, когда база слита, и перебор идет по ней. На современном железе полный перебор - это вопрос времени. В реальности это затрагивает только тех пользователей, которые не используют двухфазную  аутентификацию и при этом используют одинаковый короткий пароль для всех сайтов. В реальности, если у вас слили базу, то есть всего два варианта:

- У вас слили и все остальные данные тоже, и слитые пароли - меньшее, что вас будет волновать. Вам не будет совершенно никакой разницы, `md5` или `sha-256` у вас использовался. Потому что свою основную цель - защиту от несанционированного доступа - пароль не выполнил.
- У вас слили только данные пользователей, [забрутфорсили все пароли и выложили в открытый доступ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_LinkedIn_hack). Тогда вы извиняетесь, просите всех пользователей сменить пароль по ссылке из email и продолжаете работать как будто ничего не было.

Comment: В 5.5 версии PHP появился стандартный API для хэширования паролей. Я думаю что целесообразно приучать разработчиков к именно использованию этого API, а не самодельных функций.

Comment: @mantigatos я только за, но в вопросе нет упоминания про php (по крайней мере в тэгах). например, в .NET стандартное шифрование паролей c солью есть уже лет 10. я пытался ответить на общий вопрос, без привязки к конкретному языку.

Comment: На доступном дешёвом железе MD5 перебирается со скоростью 100 000 000 000 хэшей в секунду. 8-символьные пароли при *любой соли* перебираются за несколько часов. Всё, MD5 с точки зрения безопасности мёртв.

Comment: @Athari SHA-1 перебирается всего-лишь в два раза медленее. https://www.golubev.com/hashgpu.htm 5600M/s для MD5, 2300M/s для SHA-1 в секунду на железе 4-летней давности. достаточно долго в ответе - это часы, а не секунды. спасет только [correct horse battery staple](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: @PashaPash, Спасибо вам! `Sha-1` хэширования лучше тем `md5` да?!

Comment: @KYRAN, в криптографии не всё так просто. Можно конечно сказать, что SHA-1 лучше, чем MD5, но реальных доказательств "лучшести", Вы вряд ли получите, уж больно они схожи. И оба этих алогритма уже довольно стары, есть куда более новые алгоритмы хеширования. Но, раз у Вас возникают подобные вопросы, то с криптографией Вы знакомы мало, а значит можете выбирать любой(что md5, что sha1) - система не станет от любого выбранного решения менее безопасной.

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо за внимание! Вы прав.

Comment: Если нужно хоть как-то защититься от перебора, то надо использовать более сложные способы хэширования. Я бы предложил вам взглянуть на алгоритмы у криптовалют. Например, Scrypt (перебор на современном железе до 1 000 000 значений в секунду в связке GPU+CPU, до 300 000 на CPU) или CryptoNight (GPU использовать нельзя, а на, например, Intel Core i7 идёт перебор со скоростью всего лишь 200 значений в секунду).

Comment: @SuperCreeper я расписывал случай с точки зрения ситуации "база не утекла". если база убежала - то различные соли, уникальные для различных пользователе все еще предотвращают полный перебор с возможностью узнать пароли сразу для всех пользователей (по крайней мере для sha1).

Comment: если кому-то есть что-то добавить насчет современных алгоритмов, подходов по умолчанию в разных платформах, best practices по использованию соли - редактируйте. я переведу ответ в community wiki после первой же правки.

Comment: @PashaPash Я [в комментарии ниже](http://goo.gl/bDTz3x) указал на fallback для PHP < 5.5. Так что на ваше усмотрение.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно делать вот так:

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php

```
$options = array(
    'cost' => 12,
);
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

`password_hash()` создает случайную соль в случае, если она не была указана явно, и чаще всего это наилучший и безопасный выбор.

Comment: Спасибо но сложнее чем `Sha-1` и `md5`

Comment: Чем сложнее? Тем что две строчки вместо одной? Считать то всё равно компьютеру а не вам...

Comment: Насколько я знаю, bcrypt, как и md5 и sha1, тже устарел, и нужно использовать scrypt)

Comment: @KYRAN, если необходим fallback до версий PHP < 5.5, то Ваш алгоритм хеширования пароля (`$password = sha1($password);`) яйца выеденного не стоит. Смотрите, как это сделано у [старшеньких](https://goo.gl/lKFhE0). Если не ошибаюсь, то по части сек'юрности разработчиков Yii консультировал Энтони Феррара, создатель [password_hash](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash). Можно воспользоваться fallback-ом, который непосредственно [реализовал он сам](https://goo.gl/FMNsY2)

Comment: @mantigatos, функцию для валидации забыли добавить `password_verify($password, $hash)`, а то мало ли :)

Comment: Плюсую соль, люто, бешено. Алгоритмы хэширования (и методы их взлома) - мода, по-моему, борьба щита и меча, бесконечная. Но соль усложняет взлом без особых последствий.

Answer (score 3):

Оба метода на данный момент считаются взломанными и не рекомендуются к использованию.

Если у вас уже есть пароли, захешированные в md5, то так, как у вас делать нельзя. Все имеющиеся хэши станут невалидными и перестанут работать.
Если паролей ещё нет, то так делать нельзя тоже. Используйте другую функцию, добавьте соли. А лучше не изобретайте велосипед и найдите готовое решение

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!

Answer (score 1):

Я пользуюсь **crypt**

```
mb_substr(crypt($password, '$10$rounds=1000$ea75sit60cS1b6dC$'), 32);
```

на выходе будет что-то вроде

> sX6QsClWw6dx8dKD/TJ8..WcdA2Dca8aZqsKXcgb7pW6ZY042ACQemtzQG5DkOj8wL7wmRNqH4oLRhLH0SYPp/

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать [HMAC-SHA256](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash-hmac.php)

Comment: Основное предназначение HMAC это проверка целостности информации, а не хэширование паролей.